# Do I have to copy my django project to another machine to perform celery tasks on it?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Here is the problem - I have a server with my django project on it.

I have to perform a lot of tasks so I use celery+rabbitmq to deal with them.

Recently I discovered that server is running out of memory so I've decided to move all tasks to another dedicated server. Following this [guide](http://timbull.com/build-a-processing-queue-with-multi-threading) I've created rabbitmq cluster without copying my django project.

I am able to send tasks to celery on my new dedicated server, however celery says that tasks are unregistered e.g.

`Received unregistered task of type 'djangoapp.tasks.taskname'. The message has been ignored and discarded.`

So what should I do - just copy my django project or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, the code containing the tasks needs to be on box that will run them. That is, the `djangoapp.tasks` code needs to be there.

---

Naturally, all its dependencies (likely model code) and configuration (settings) will need to be there too.
You could try to save some space by only including those parts, but I really don't think it's worth it.

You should run the entire codebase (project + apps) on both servers.

---

For information, when you start Celery, registered tasks are displayed. You can use this to check everything is properly set-up.

Answer (score 0):

each celery worker server should be running a copy of the same code, yes